# udev rules not working for ThinkPad X200 dock

Tags: arch-linux, udev

Learning this as I go, so excuse me if I'm totally missing the point.

I'm running Arch on a ThinkPad X200 and I want to get the dock to work so that I can sit at my desk charging and displaying to an external monitor. I have been working on this issue for nearly a week trying many different things and different approaches, udev being the one I think will work best.

Here is the udev output for when it's docked:

```
UDEV  [7979.317053] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/027
DEVNUM=027
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_5
ID_MODEL=1005
ID_MODEL_ENC=1005
ID_MODEL_ID=1005
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:5
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_5
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=17ef_1005
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090001:090002:
ID_VENDOR=17ef
ID_VENDOR_ENC=17ef
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Lenovo
ID_VENDOR_ID=17ef
MAJOR=189
MINOR=26
PRODUCT=17ef/1005/1
SEQNUM=2995
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:seat:
TYPE=9/0/2
USEC_INITIALIZED=7975952454
```

Here is the udev output for when it's undocked:

```
UDEV  [7996.175393] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/027
DEVNUM=027
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=26
PRODUCT=17ef/1005/1
SEQNUM=3003
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/2
USEC_INITIALIZED=7996171763
```

Here is the udev rule I created:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{PRODUCT}=="17ef/1005/1",  RUN+="/usr/local/bin/docked.sh"
```

This is the `/usr/local/bin/docked.sh` script I made using dockd to handle monitor output:

```
#!/bin/bash

dockd --set docked
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, and I appologize if I left anything out that is needed to solve the problem.